# Calligraphy fonts doesn't work from style.xml

Tags: android, fonts

Hi I try to use [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)

I have this in my activity:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

and i want to use fonts in this layout (it is layout for fragment):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fontPatch="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/fragmentMainBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/grid_0"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/grid_0"

tools:context=".app.mainscreen.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MissingPrefix">


    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/statusTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/fontDexlineProRegular"/>

//...
```

and my styles:

```
<style name="fontDexlineProRegular" parent="android:TextAppearance">
    <item name="fontPath">fonts/DexlinePro-Regular.ttf</item>
</style>
```

this doesn't work.

but when i try use this: fonts works

```
//...
<TextView
android:id="@+id/statusTv"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
fontPath="fonts/DexlinePro-Regular.ttf"/>
//...
```

How can i set up fonts from style? Whats wrong in style.xml?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: i have no error message. Only font don't change...

Comment: when i change font name (and all references) write it this: `Can't create asset from fonts/DexlineProBolt.otf. Make sure you have passed in the correct path and file name.`  but font is there

Comment: Okay, is your `asset` folder placed inside `src/main/`? Inside `res` doesn't work.

Comment: yes i have assets on right place

Comment: I added this: `CalligraphyConfig.initDefault( ...` and its start work :/

Comment: Cool! Glad to hear. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this: `CalligraphyConfig.initDefault( ...` and its start work :/

Answer (score 0):

> **Put your `DexlinePro_Regular.ttf` into assets folder**

Note: Please take undersore with ttf file...

And Set to textview..

```
   TextView statusTv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusTv);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "DexlinePro_Regular.ttf");
    statusTv.setTypeface(font);
```